# Specify container div for a portlet

Tags: html, liferay, portlet

Is it possible to specify anywhere in liferay portlet, that what will be the container div for that portlet? in short I have multiple portlets on my page. I want to Place one portlet inside a DIV. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I never used it but I think I'd be helpfull ;)

Enable portlets (styled divs) as sortables and use the connectWith option to allow sorting between columns.

take a look there --> 
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

Answer (score 0):

Every portlet is always contained in several characterizing DIVs automatically.

To give an example: You can address the lower left article on http://www.liferay.com ("Liferay delivers open source enterprise solutions...") based on the portlet's id (e.g. truly unique) as

```
#p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_n5AQ_ { background:green; }
```

(note: "56" is the portlet's id, Liferay numbers the default portlets to have short identifiers)

As it's displayed in a "Web Content Display Portlet" (56, old human readable name: "Journal content display"), you can also address all instances of this portlet through a more descriptive class (but that hits all "Web Content Display" portlets:

```
.portlet-journal-content { background: red; }
```

and the portlet itself attributes its content with the "journal-content-article" class, so you can also go with

```
.journal-content-article { background: blue; }
```

Just examine the page source/DOM with Firebug to find the relevant information that you need - especially for custom portlets the portlet id is a bit more complex, but it's all systematic and (IMHO) quite easy to understand when you examine it on this level.